# Running EF Core migrations in Heroku

Tags: c#, entity-framework, heroku

I'm currently developing a prototype in .NET Core and for the sake of simplicity, I went with Docker/Heroku.

What I noticed is that when trying to run the migrations via `heroku dotnet run ef database update`, the `dotnet` CLI was not available. I quickly noticed this was due to my final image having only the runtime, not the sdk. The question I have is: what would make the most sense in order to be able to run migrations while at the same time having a lighter image running only the runtime? Am I making to big a deal out of having only the runtime?

This is how my current image is, in order to be able to run the migrations as I currently am:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out ./

RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

# Set ASPNETCORE_URLS to run the app on the port Heroku exposes.
# Kestrel run by default on 5000/1 and Heroku doesn't allow that.
CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet Lazarus.dll
```

It just feels wrong that I have both the SDK and I have to install EF CLI in the production image, so any insight is welcome!

Comment: I too would feel wrong to have SDK and EF installed on production docker image. In my opinion, DB migration is a deployment step, not a post production activity. So, I would use a pre-built image of SDK w/EF from docker hub during deployment, mount the migration scripts to the image, set the connection info in ENV variables and execute the migration commands. Then push the light container out to production.

Comment: Right, I'm just not too sure how to achieve that, not in a clean way at least.

Comment: I have run into this, which reassures me that I must not be the only one that has stumbled upon this: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15857

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After playing around with different options, the easiest/simplest approach was to run the migrations before the startup of the application hooking into the webhost, in the actual application code.

By creating an extension function such as:

```
public static IWebHost MigrateDatabase<T>(this IWebHost webHost) where T : DbContext
{
    using(var scope = webHost.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        try
        {
            var db = services.GetRequiredService<T>();
            db.Database.Migrate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while migrating the database.");
        }
    }
    return webHost;
}
```

It can be used in the main entry point as follows:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
        .Build()
        .MigrateDatabase<DatabaseContext>()
        .Run();
}
```

While it does not run the migrations as part of the deployment process, but as part of the startup process, I felt it was much easier and required less moving parts in order to get started. This also allowed shipping a much smaller image which simply contains the runtime and not the SDK along with all the tooling.